# QuickBlox custom table -- Create relation and getting related records on iOS

Tags: ios, quickblox

How do I create relation between two custom tables with the iOS SDK?

Do I just set the parentID on QBCOCustomObject to create it?

On the REST doc there is a way to get multiple related records, how do I do that with Quickblox iOS sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **parentID** field.

How it works: for example you have 2 entities: Movies & Comments. Each comment has parentID=movieID. If you will delete this Movie - all Comments will be deleted also.

To get related records just use ***extendedRequest*** param

```
NSMutableDictionary *getRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[getRequest setObject:@"31212412a1269123" forKey:@"_parent_id"];

[QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName:@"Comment" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self];
```